# how to refresh layout in on swipe to refresh android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a recycler view inside a swipeRefresh every time i try to scroll on top the swipe to refresh method gets called and the layout is refreshed, but i want to refresh the layout only on scrolling to the top of the screen. Does anybody have an answer to this question.

Any help is appreciated, Thank you

My layout is as shown below.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Why is there a `RelativeLayout` between the `RecyclerView` and the `SwipeRefreshLayout`? Shouldn't the `SwipeRefreshLayout` be the direct parent of the `RecyclerView`? see https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. I had to rearrange my code to get it working.
Now the lyout refreshes on on reaching the top of the screen.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/swipe_container"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [setOnRefreshListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html#setOnRefreshListener(android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener)) method of SwipeRefreshLayout

```
upload_swipe_refresh_layout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            webServiceCall();
            upload_swipe_refresh_layout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });
```

For keep refreshing

```
upload_swipe_refresh_layout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        upload_swipe_refresh_layout.setRefreshing(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am using setOnRefreshListener, but the problem  it is getting called everytime i try to scroll on upwards. while i want to refresh on reaching the top of the screen.

Comment: then you can keep it refreshing all the time